# React-router-dom not rendering components (express,react,redux,mongodb)

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

Hello Everyone I'm having trouble getting this to work. 
Express should only load the index page once when requested react-router should take over from then.

**express code**:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./config/keys').MONGOURI;

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected');
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// req.body kan hierdoor json zijn
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Express session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  proxy: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/dist')));
// static route loading index.html from there react.router takes over
// it is just offering the index.html file
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/dist/index.html'));
});


// process.env werkt op elk platform
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Express server is running on port ${PORT}`));

after this the app component should be rendered

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers';
import App from './containers/App';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
// store
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware,
  ),
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

the app component is just routes to a home component and a login component 
with as fallback a 404 page

**index.js (frontend first load)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers';
import App from './containers/App';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
// store
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware,
  ),
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

None of the components are getting loaded. Adding an h1 to app loads.
I feel like express keeps on serving the index page..

**App component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import Login from './Login';

const Home = () => <h2>this is the homepage</h2>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" Component={Login} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

express will serve as an api to save users and process other data.

[image: this is the my directory tree]

Comment: does your index.html file have a way of rendering the js? You're correct in assuming that the index file is likely the file that your express file is rendering, is the console showing you any errors?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with does your index.html file have a way of rendering the js. But adding jsx/html to my app component renders it.  And no no errors in the console.

Comment: @ArielSalem I thought it was express sending index again. But webpack devserver so without Express just the frontend the react-router doesn't work either.

Comment: currently your express server is handling `/` routes by serving up an index.html file:

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/dist/index.html'));
});

Normally that index.html file would have script tag to serve up js:

`<script src="../app.js"></script>`

However, as Curtis below mentioned, your devserver likely isn't working because you had capitalized the `component` property in the `Route` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Switch` to below. Notice the lowercase component in the code above.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

I fixed it by testing react on its own to make sure it work (before figuring out express). Heres my test file.

```
const Home = () => {
    console.log("home")
    return <h2>this is the homepage</h2>
};
const Login = () => {
    console.log("login")
    return <h2>this is the loginpage</h2>
};
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("here", this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Index = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

export default Index;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the "exact" prop intelligently.

Comment: What do you mean by that?